# Does the Real Money Auction House need Cash to put your items online?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've heard a bit about the in-game Real Money AH, and i'm a bit excited about it. Thing is, my friends are also saying on how you need to pony up some cash to list your item on the Cash AH before being able to let others buy the item you are trying to sell.

Is this true? I'm trying to find the FAQ but i dont see anything like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no upfront fee.  There is a transaction free of $1 for equipment (armor, weapons, jewellery, etc), and 15% of final sale price for commodities (gems, dyes, recipes - items that can be sold in bulk).  You only get charged one fee or the other.  This is only paid if the auction is successful.

[There's a FAQ here.](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-auction-house-general-information;jsessionid=075C33B4CD521EDE5D757BDE1A209264.blade34_08_bnet-support#q5)

Comment: So does this mean that if the sale price is $1.17 or less, then you actually lose money? (1.17 * 85% - 1 ~= 0)

Comment: someone needs to answer mike cooper's question.

Comment: According to the link, equipment has only a flat 1$ fee while commodities only have a 15% fee. The only way to lose money would be to put up a piece of equipment for less than a dollar, which is probably forbidden by the interface

Comment: As Alex says, the fees are mutually exclusive.  You sell a piece of armor for $5, you receive $4.  You sell a recipe for $5, you receive $4.25 back.  I'll add a little clarification.

Comment: You should describe the differences between the two payment times Battle.net Balance and PayPal.  PayPal ( cash ) comes with some additional fees where as the Battle.net Balance ( Blizzard Gift Cards Basically ) do not.